# how can i mic a 7 piece drumkit to record it in a professional studio

Tags: recording, drums, electronic-drumset

The type of drum is a standard kit ....and i need to know the types of mics i will need to use and also their type (condenser/dynamic),brand names along with frequency response,directionality in terms of polar patterns and as well as sensitivity  measures of each mic in each piece

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Music.  Just a heads up my friend.  There will be votes to close your question as asking for brand names is considered off topic.  Also, in it's current format it might lead to a charge that all answers will be opinion based.  You might want to edit the question before it get's closed.  You might want to take the tour and read more to better understand how to format questions that work well on this site.  Try clicking here (https://music.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Micing drums is a skill and an art and takes a long time to master. A pro studio should have the kit and the skills and every engineer will have their own favourite mics.and mic positions.

Answer (score 3):

Use whatever the studio has.
Use their engineer to set it up.

If they already have a studio kit, consider using that instead.* Their engineer will be very familiar with it.

The time to be learning how to mic up a large drum kit in a room you don't know with mics you don't know **is not now**. You will not get it right in a week, maybe not even a month.

It takes years to know instinctively what will work on a kit even in a room you know with mics you already know.

Half of the data you are requesting is really unimportant to that learning curve, it's merely incidental, & one engineer will use a cardioid dynamic mic where another would use an omni condenser.
Both are correct.

…and one late point…
A good mic cupboard to do this can cost in excess of 10 thousand dollars.

*Anecdotally, at one time in my life I had the …ermm… pleasure of being hired to do a 'best of the local bands' album. So we had basically one band every 2 days for about a month.
All the drummers brought their own kits. 70% of them ended up using the studio kit because theirs sounded like pants.
For the more insistent drummers I did a fast tune-up & got something respectable out of them [usually using the studio cymbals]. Most times, though, even if the drummer preferred his own kit, the rest of the band managed to talk him out of it ;)

Comment: Super answer - +1. OP says professional studio. Odds are it's already set up! And you're spot on about studio kits. Why would they be there if they weren't doing a superb job already..?

Comment: I hear that really good drummers may want to bring their own snare drum and perhaps some cymbals to a professional studio, and use the rest as is.

Comment: @Jos - experience counts for everything. I can take my kit into any studio & have it ready to be miked inside 10 mins. I also know how best to mic it, in general, & know it is already tuned for recording, not live. I would still make extensive use of the in-house engineer's advice, based on his knowledge & experience of the room & mic cupboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I'd guess about one in twenty drummers are as organised as you.

Comment: @PeterJ - it's possibly more that fewer than 1 in 20 drummers is predominantly a sound engineer/producer who also happens to be a player.. & very very finnicky when I'm recording ;)

Comment: And if it ends up that you absolutely are on your own for micing, a good starting point is a matched pair of mics over the drum kit (about 6–8 feet above the floor). Add a third mic on the bass drum if needed and then see if anything else needs to be more closely mic'd. But if you're paying for studio time, you don't want to spend that time on amateur sound engineering if there's an option to have someone who knows what they're doing take care of ti.